# How to put the navigation bar in one line using beamerthemesplit?

Tags: beamer

I'm using a beamerthemesplit package in beamer to create slides for presentation. I get a header with 2 split columns (1 on the left for section, 1 on the right for subsection's name). My problem is I want the section to be expanded horizontally instead of vertically. I mean I want the section's name to go from left to right instead of up to down, followed by the subsection's name below of the section name.

I know I'll get 2 columns because I use beamerthemesplit. But I still want to use this because I like the color and the overall output. And I want the section to go from left to right because I dont want the bar to go wider as I have many sections.

Simply say, I'm trying to get an output looks like [this](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/tumath/students/latex/Beamer_Template_handout.pdf).

Comment: The link you provided doesn't work for me.

Comment: The `infolines` outer theme (`\useoutertheme{infolines}`) will only show you the current section and subsection.

Comment: @Gonzalo I fixed the link by removing a blank.

Answer (score 9):

1. According to the `beamer` user
   guide, the `split` theme is still
   included only for compatibility
   reasons; you should refrain from
   choosing it if you're using a recent
   version of the `beamer` package.
2. You can get pretty close to your
   linked file's appearance with the
   following preamble:

   ```
   \documentclass[compress]{beamer}
   \usetheme{Madrid}
   \useoutertheme[footline=authortitle,subsection=false]{miniframes}
   ```

If you only use sections (no subsections), then the only difference with your linked file will be in the footline, which is not split in two colors. (If you *do* use subsections, you will see a second line in the headline, with dots representing frames.)

The user guide (`beameruserguide.pdf`, usually located in your TEXMF tree at the path `doc/latex/beamer`) provides in its Part III a nice visual description of all themes, together with more fine-tuning options for your presentation's appearance.

Comment: @hotaru: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I merged your two accounts together now and converted your "thank you" post to a comment. Please accept (and up-vote, if you can) this answer to show that it helped you.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer That's fine and sorry for that. I'm a little bit confused of using features here. Thanks btw.

Comment: @hotaru: it looks like you don't have enough reputation for upvoting yet. You can still accept answers though (by clicking on the checkmark on the left). You can only accept one answer per question, but you can revert your decision later.

Answer (score 2):

You can use these:

```
\documentclass{beamer}  
\usetheme{Warsaw}  
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}
```

It is almost the same as your link, but with a difference that it shows subsections of each section as dots below that section.